# eMMC Memory Layout for SWUpdate

Tags: linux, u-boot, swupdate, sdmmc

In order to implement SWUpdate Dual Copy (A/B) update on an eMMC embedded Linux sistem, I'd like to partitioning the eMMC so as to have two kernel partitions with the goal of switch from uImageA to uImageB.

Today the memory layout is the following:

- /dev/mmcblk0p1 as VFAT containing SPL, U-Boot and the kernel
- /dev/mmmcblkpX that contains the various rootFSs.

Now I'd like to move the kernel out side of VFAT partition to a non VFAT partition.

How I could do that?

In other words, if I have U-boot in VFAT partition, how I could run the Linux Kernel if it is placed in /dev/mmcblk0p2 (copied with dd).
I'm "preparing" the eMMC as follow:

- /dev/mmcblkp1, VFAT, SPL + U-Boot
- /dev/mmcblkp2, dd if=uImageA.bin of=/dev/mmcblkp2 etc
- /dev/mmcblkp3, dd if=uImageB.bin of=/dev/mmcblkp3 etc
- /dev/mmcblkp4, EXT4 containing rootFSA
- /dev/mmcblkp5, EXT4 containing rootFSB

But I don't know how, at u-boot level, load uImage from /dev/mmcblkp2 partition.
Today, i'm loading the kernel using fatload command.

Comment: Please add the U-Boot config to the post.

Comment: Why do you think you need separate partitions for each uImage? You can install as many versions of uImage files as space allows in the **/boot** directory of the root filesystem. You would need a naming scheme, or use symbolic links for the primary and backup versions. If your kernel has loadable modules (which would be stored in the rootfs), this makes more sense than separating these files.

Comment: @sawdust because I'd like to use SWUpdate partitions update mechanism.

Comment: @stark what do you mean?

Comment: SWUpdate has [support for updating a single file inside a filesystem](https://sbabic.github.io/swupdate/swupdate.html). Dedicating a partition to a non-filesystem image tends to be wasteful. You will over-allocate the partition to accommodate larger future images. Separating the kernel from its rootfs creates a bookkeeping task.

Comment: Yes, but i'd like to implement dual copy A/B also for rootFS dedicating two partitions also for rootFS

Comment: If you insist on reading raw blocks (rather than a file within a filesystem), then U-Boot requires you to specify the source (e.g. the start of the eMMC partition) by the absolute block number of the medium. Study https://docs.u-boot.org/en/latest/usage/cmd/mmc.html FYI you're perpetuating an old, crude, inefficient method that was used back when U-Boot didn't have ext3/4 and/or UBIFS support. But modern versions of U-Boot do support those filesystems.

Comment: @sawdust You convinced me! I'll use an EXT4 partition to store the kernel. I understand that the ext4 filesystem is more robust, but I can't figure out how to take advantage of the potential of ext4 at the u-boot level. I mean, I'll ex4load uImage file from the ext4 partition to the RAM, and then?

Comment: That's not what I meant. You would "*take advantage of the potential of ext4 at the u-boot level*" by storing the kernel image within the rootfs (where its loadable modules are already stored). That's the rationale for having the **/boot** directory.